# SLF4J code snippet to log messages into a file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am currently using SLF4J with `log4j-over-slf4j` and `logback-classic`.

The program processes files in a loop.

I need to create a separate log file for each iteration of the program. Can someone point me to the sample code or code snippet? I have done enough research but running in circles with SLF4J, log4j and Kogback.

Preferably, I would like to do all configuration programmatically, instead of a properties file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Logback's `SiftingAppender` http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender. SLF4J and log4j are irrelevant here.

Edit: Follow the example configuration XML file. Change the line

`MDC.put("userid", "Alice");`

to set a different `userId` after each iteration of the program loop, then each run will have a different output file.

Comment: Thanks, could you possible direct me to a sample implementation link?

Comment: Thanks, I cannot use any XML based configuration. Everything has to be programmatic.